# iFrame redirecting & reload homepage issue on mobile phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, jquery-mobile, mobile

My two below code are working good. 1st code working good on pc and 2nd code working on mobile phone. but i wants to auto reload after 30 sec on mobile using 1st code and 2nd code agent. 
how to i add 2nd mobile agent code on 1st code?

1st code:

```
<script>
window.setInterval("reloadIFrame();", 30000);
function reloadIFrame() {
document.getElementById("test").src="http://example.com";
}
</script>
```

2nd code:

```
<script>
var isMobile = function() {
return /(iphone|ipod|ipad|android|blackberry|windows 
ce|palm|symbian)/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
};
if(isMobile()) {
window.location.href = "https://example.com";
}
</script>
```

sorry for not good english.
Please help me to solve it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use same delay function in mobile page too as far as I can understand. Here you can try this, ask if something is wrong:

```
/* Define the functions */

var reloadIFrame = function() {
    document.getElementById("test").src="http://example.com";
};

var isMobile = function() {
    return /(iphone|ipod|ipad|android|blackberry|windows ce|palm|symbian)/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
};

/* Begin */

if (isMobile()) {
    window.setInterval("reloadIFrame();", 30000);
}
```